# "Disk boot failure, insert system disk and press enter" after replacing HDD with SSD

Tags: boot, bios

I have replaced the nonworking HDD in my old PC with an SSD and BIOS detects the SSD drive. Now every time I boot, I get the message

> Disk boot failure, insert system disk and press enter.

Any suggestions what might help?

Comment: You may need new BIOS for the computer, or (depending on how old) it may not be compatible.

Comment: Most likely the SSD you are booting from is not the one you set as boot device in the BIOS - change boot sequence in the BIOS to put your new boot disk first.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck I have done that already

Comment: What OS are you running? Windows 10 would most likely see how it is configured and work, but older windows versions will likely be very strict about it and will require manually editing config files and pure luck to get it fixed unless you don't mind reinstalling windows, which will definitely fix the issue

Comment: And you might need to fix the MBR too.

Comment: @LPChip I cannot run any OS since it doesnt want to run my SSD

Comment: Since the BIOS detects the OS, it is a matter of installing an OS to be sure that it works. Trying to fix the OS that is on the SSD is going to be a challenge though. So the solution is going to be, Reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the BIOS detects the SSD, the solution is going to be to reinstall your OS.

During the installation, you select the SSD as destination, and the OS installation will make sure the SSD is setup correctly.

You have to make sure the SSD is the startup drive in the BIOS and that the install media is being used during installation.

For example, on most modern systems, you set the boot drive to your SSD, and there is a key you can press during POST to go into the boot selection menu. From there you select the device that holds the install medium, such as a USB stick or CD.

If the bios does not offer support for a boot menu, you have to set the install medium as first boot device, and the SSD second, install the OS and once the first stage is done and it reboots, remove the install medium so it boots to the SSD.

Comment: Thank you for help, but I found the issue to be a totally different story. I found out, that my BIOS does not support SSDs, on official page it says it supports, but when I took a look at the exact model, I discovered that it doesnt support SSDs

Comment: @TBQP Ah, well, that is something I could not have guessed, given that you did not mention anywhere that you were replacing the HDD on a very old PC. PC's of 4 years or newer all supports SSD. If you had mentioned that it was an old pc, I would've considered that option as well.

Comment: Also, in the past you have mentioned that the BIOS did see the SSD, but that comment is now removed. If you had said there that it didn't, it was clear from the start.

Comment: Yeah.. It could display the name of the SSD but obviously it doesnt have drivers for SSD, since when I ran just a test Windows installation it showed me my SSD in partitions, not as a solid one disk (And also, the pc is 10 yrs old :D)